# undefined method `model_name' for User:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined, simple-form

im having aa problem with simple_form gem on ruby on rails. I'm using an instance variable but when i declare it on my partial for it appears "undefined method `model_name' for WelcomePageController:Class" i don't know what's going on. I've tried to solve it but it ssems imposible to me

**this is my controller page**

```
class WelcomePageController < ApplicationController

 def index
 end

 def new
    @neword = WelcomePageController.new
 end

 def create
 @neword = WelcomePageController.new(words_params)  
 end

 private

 def words_params
  params.require(:words_input).permit(:word, :definition, :example)
 end

end
```

**this is my partial form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @neword do |f| %>

<%= f. input :word, label: "insert a word"%>

<%= f. text :definition, label: "give a definition" %>

<%= f.text :example, label: "give an exmaple" %>

<%= f. button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

**and this is my new view**

```
<h1>hi, again</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

hope you colud help me out :)

Comment: The object you pass to `simple_form_for` should be a model, the instance variable you're defining is a controller.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like @neword should be an instance of an ActiveRecord (eg a Model),  but you are providing an instance of WelcomePageController.new (a Controller). Do you have any Database-Tables? Then you should have a Model class with the same name (e.g. "Word") which you should instantiate instead of the Controller

```
@neword = Word.create
```